# Hard cache busting of assets w/ Compass

Tags: compass-sass, gruntjs

I would like to have a hard cache busting with Compass, i.e. have hash-suffixed assets.

Compass is currently using a soft cache busting by adding a `?v` parameter in the query string, but this apparently not supported by every cdn service, and so I would like to avoid this and encode the file hash directly in the filename (`myfile-2q7de.png`).

Is it possible ? My current approach was to copy all my assets, hash them all, then write a mapping file and use it in a minimal Sass extension to get the real file path from it's non-hashed path. It works great, except with spritesheets : it makes Compass add the hash into the sprites class names, which makes them unusable :

```
.sprite-myfile-2q7de {
    ...
}
```

I should probably add that I'm using Grunt to do all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compass already adds a hash as a cache buster in the generated sprite sheets (eg `icons-sf6a3361a01.png`).

For other images, you can use the following code in your `config.rb`, which is found in the [documentation](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/):

```ruby
asset_cache_buster do |path, real_path|
  if File.exists?(real_path)
    pathname = Pathname.new(path)
    modified_time = File.mtime(real_path).strftime("%s")
    new_path = "%s/%s-%s%s" % [pathname.dirname, pathname.basename(pathname.extname), modified_time, pathname.extname]

    {:path => new_path, :query => nil}
  end
end
```

Thus, the SCSS code

```scss
.icon-cloud {
  background: image-url("weather-cloud.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

generates an image with an embedded cache buster (`weather-cloud-1365271586.png`):

```css
.icon-cloud {
  background: url('../img/weather-cloud-1365271586.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Warning: Compass doesn't duplicate or rename the image. You'll have to create a rewrite rule that will allow your web server to serve the good image.